# Excessive resource usage Process time on /usr/bin/php 

Tags: php, hosting, vps

I have just moved my site over to VPS hosting. I am using WHM and Cpanel to manage my site.

Since the transfer I have been receiving many, many emails stating that the processing time for PHP has been exceeded. Up to 100 emails a day.

This is the exact email details

> Time:    Thu Jan 19 11:41:11 2012 +1100
>
> Account:    wpinsite
>
> Resource:    Process Time
>
> Exceeded:    2091 > 1800 (seconds)
>
> Executable:    /usr/bin/php
>
> Command Line: /usr/bin/php
>
> PID:    24625
>
> Killed:    Yes

Could someone please help to as why I keep receiving these emails and should I act upon them.

I.E Do I set a setting in WHM to increase the PHP timeout limit and if so where would I do this?

Or should I simply ignore these emails and is there a setting in WHM to turn them off, if so where would I find this?

Comment: Are you running any heave background PHP scripts?

Comment: Not that I can see. I wrote to the Web Host support team and that stated that email is fine and is sent by the WHM firewall. They didn't mention if I needed to increase the PHP threshold or disable the notification and if so, how to disable the notification.

Answer (score 7):

This is an old post and I know this won't help Jason, but I'm hoping it will help someone else.

I'm going to guess that you're using FastCGI (FCGI) as your PHP handler. If so, that's what's causing this.

The Apache website says, "[FastCGI] starts a sufficient number instances of the CGI program to handle concurrent requests, and these programs remain running to handle further incoming requests."

So there's really nothing wrong with your system and, even though you may not like having your PHP scripts unmonitored, the best way to stop the alerts is to set add PHP to the ignore list.

Since you are using WHM Cpanel, go to the CSF control area, scroll down to the "Edit lfd ignore file" section, select "csf.pignore - Process Tracking" and add **exe:/usr/bin/php**  to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The resource notification is sent by the firewall in the vps. so, ask your provider to increase the process execution time in firewall config file or ask to ignore the php in the firewall. This is only way to avoid the notification from the server side . Otherwise you have to optimize your php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the time for this directly in CSF, and it is pretty straightforward - they explain all of the parameters right inside the configuration file.  However, this is telling you that some piece of code is keeping these php processes alive and thus may be indicating an issue that needs attention.  There could also be times where this could occur due to exploit - so you really have to take a look at the pattern for those alerts and make an informed decision from the details you see there.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the **ConfigServer Security & Firewall** screen on WHM, opened up the **Firewall Configuratio**n section,

Then Looked for the option called `PT_USERTIME` (tracks and reports if any process exceeds the time) and increased it to 3600.

**Notes:**
On my server, I have very specific data sync jobs that despite my maximum efforts to split up and optimize, sometimes takes 45 minutes per run.

For most customer facing environments you probably don't need any PHP code to run this long unless you have some sort of relay or data sync going on - I would definitely start with attempts to optimize, or look for any delays or unwanted loops etc. first.